# Run external command in inputrc mapping, without modifying current line

Tags: bash, zsh, tmux

I have mapped `C-h`, `C-j`, `C-k`, `C-m` key combinations in `tmux.conf` to switch between panes, but really miss the `C-h` combination for backspace when using bash / zsh.

I have enabled `vi` mode in `~/.inputrc` and was thinking of mapping `C-h` to `backward-delete-char` in `vi-insert` mode, and to run `tmux select-pane -L` in `vi-command` mode.

How can I add a mapping in `vi-command` mode to run the command `tmux select-pane -L` in background, without modifying the current line and its cursor position?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Bash

This is possible, but not through inputrc. (This file belongs to the Readline library, which – although mostly known from Bash – is actually a generic text input library used by many different programs and doesn't really deal with shell-specific things like "running a command".)

Instead, this is a custom action provided by Bash itself (not available in other Readline-using programs), and has to be defined using Bash's `bind` builtin, specifically, the `-x` option:

```
bind -m vi-command -x '"\C-h": tmux select-pane -L'
```

#### Zsh

Zsh's ZLE is different, in that it *is* specifically part of the actual zsh shell, but it also doesn't have a straightforward "execute command" option. Instead, you have to define a custom ZLE *widget*, which can only call a shell function, and then bind that to a key.

1. Define a function that runs the thing.

   ```
   tmux-go-left() { tmux select-pane -L; }
   ```

   When running an interactive program, its stdin must be redirected from `/dev/tty` (otherwise it'll read EOF and immediately quit), and `zle -I` must be called to "invalidate" the screen contents when the program exits (otherwise the cursor will be in the wrong location). For example:

   ```
   open-htop() { htop </dev/tty; zle -I; }
   ```
2. Define a widget that calls the function.

   ```
   zle -N tmux-go-left
   zle -N open-htop
   ```

   If the function name is not provided, it's assumed to be the same as the widget name.
3. Bind a key to the widget.

   ```
   bindkey -a '\C-h' tmux-go-left
   bindkey -v '\C-p' open-htop
   ```

   It seems that `-v` selects Vi insert mode; `-a` selects Vi command mode.

Sources:

- `man zshzle`
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57539180/why-is-interactive-command-breaking-when-using-zsh-widget-to-execute-it

Comment: There is a missing single quote in the `bind -m vi-command...`  command. I tried to make an edit suggestion, but it was rejected since the change is less than 6 chars.

Comment: Both the `bash` and `zsh` solutions worked perfectly. Thank you for the working solution and detailed explanation.

Comment: Would it be possible to do something like this using inputrc. Delete from current cursor position to beginning of line, and store in one buffer. Delete from current position to end of line and store in another buffer. Execute the external command, and then regenerate the original line from the copied buffers.

Comment: In vim I would have been possible with something like

`"ad^"bd$:!tmux select-pane -L<cr>"ap"bpg;`

But of course, I wouldn't have to do this in vim since it is possible to run a command without modifying the current line.